# Поиск индекса наибольшего элемента в последовательности

Tags: python, while

Недавно начал изучение python и параллельно решаю задачки с http://pythontutor.ru/. И застрял на задаче по циклам while.

> Текст задачи: Условие
>   Последовательность состоит из натуральных чисел и завершается числом 0. Определите индекс наибольшего элемента последовательности. Если наибольших элементов несколько, выведите индекс первого из них. Нумерация элементов начинается с нуля.

Мой код решения:

```
max = 0
element = -1
index = -1 
while element != 0:
    element = int(input())
    if element > max:
        max = element
        index += 1
print(index)
```

Тем не менее, два варианта не проходят. Например: 
Входные данные:2 1 3 0 Ответ: 2 (у меня выдает 1)

Я в общем-то вижу ошибку, но не понимаю как реализовать, что бы решалось не только если цифры вводятся не равномерно по возрастанию\убыванию (такие варианты все решились)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы проверяете увеличиваете индекс только когда находите большее число, а надо его увеличивать всегда.

```
max = 0
element = -1
index = -1
index_max = 0
while element != 0:
    element = int(input())
    index += 1
    if element > max:
        max = element
        index_max = index        
print(index_max)
```

И ваш код можно улучшить, если взять за начальные значения не -1 и 0, а значение первого элемента и его индекс.

Comment: хм, тогда он не решает правильно другие варианты, такие как: 
Входные данные: 1 7 9 0 Ответ: 2(выдает 1)

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы найти индекс наибольшего элемента последовательности, можно использовать встроенную функцию max():

```
numbers = map(int, iter(input, '0'))
index, max_value = max(enumerate(numbers), key=lambda i_v: i_v[1])
print(index)
```

Код принимает целые числа от пользователя—одно число на каждой новой строчке, пока не встретится ноль (`'0'`). Встроенная функция `iter(function, end_value)` генерирует последовательность, вызывая функцию `function()` до тех пор пока не встретится `end_value`.

Встроенная функция `map()` преобразует строки в числа в данном случае.

Встроенная функция `enumerate()` генерирует пары индекс, значение. `lambda i_v: i_v[1]` функция извлекает значение из пары, служа ключём для сравнения, таким образом пары сравниваются по соответствующим значениям.

`max()` возвращает пару с наибольшим значением.

---

Использование `max()` в Питон коде более предпочтительно по сравнению с while-циклом более подходящим для C кода для решения задачи "Поиск наибольшего элемента в последовательности" в Питоне. Старайтесь использовать подходящие идиомы для выбранного языка. Если сама задача неинтересна, а просто ошибку в while-цикле хотите найти, то спрашивайте именно об этом.

Comment: Возможно, но для начинающего большая часть того, что вы привели не говорит о чём-то, ибо я просто о таком не знаю. Хотя, безусловно, это интересно

Comment: @Howuhh как я сказал, если вы изучаете циклы, то спрашивайте о циклах. Ответы на Stack Overflow предназначены не только лично для вас, а для посетителей из веб-поисковиков, которых интересует как максимум найти и вызов max() является более идиоматичным способом наибольшее значение/индекс найти чем while цикл в Питоне. На будущее, имейте ввиду когда заголовок вопроса пишете (что человек ожидает в качестве ответа).

Comment: Заголовок был скорректирован не мной:/

Comment: @Howuhh у вас слишком общий заголовок был, исправление совершенно оправдано. Более точно, можно было использовать: "найти индекс наибольшего значения используя while цикл" (сейчас уже не надо редактировать). Избегайте заголовки с нулевой информацией типа: "помогите, не работает". Представьте что кто-то уже задал вопрос по вашей проблеме, напишите такой заголовок, на который вы бы кликнули в поисковике (заголовок должен отражать проблему как вы её понимаете).

Comment: Хорошо, я понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вот так
Я изменил вывод так, чтобы он отображал не только индекс значения, но и само значение. Чтобы не путаться. Да и алгоритм поправил, ибо корень всех бед 'index=-1', а считать нужно с единицы

```
max = 0  
index = 1  
element = - 1  
while element != 0:  
    element = int(input())  
    if element > max:  
        max = element  
        max_index = index  
    index += 1  
print(str(max_index)+'('+str(max) +')')
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я попробую

Answer (score -1):

```
elements = []
while True:
    element = int(input())
    if element:
        elements.append(element)
    else: break

index = elements.index(max(elements))
```

Comment: Спасибо, я знал, что так можно сделать, но по условию задачника предполагается, что я ещё не знаком со списками.