# Как задать признак конца ввода?

Tags: python

Ввожу в консоль строку из чисел. Как задать признак конца ввода? Например, считывать до тех пор, пока не будет символ '0' и т.д

Comment: [пример кода, читающий строки с числами пока `'0'` не встретится](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/614667/23044)

Answer (score 5):

```
In [2]: for i in iter(input, 'stop'):
   ...:     print('Вы ввели: ' + i)
   ...:
hello
Вы ввели: hello
world
Вы ввели: world
stop
```

Из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter):

> Return an iterator object. The first argument is interpreted very
>   differently depending on the presence of the second argument. Without
>   a second argument, object must be a collection object which supports
>   the iteration protocol (the `__iter__()` method), or it must support the
>   sequence protocol (the `__getitem__()` method with integer arguments
>   starting at 0). If it does not support either of those protocols,
>   `TypeError` is raised. **If the second argument, sentinel, is given, then
>   object must be a callable object. The iterator created in this case
>   will call object with no arguments for each call to its `__next__()`
>   method; if the value returned is equal to sentinel, `StopIteration` will
>   be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.**

Answer (score 0):

Вот так, например:

```
lines = []

while True:
    line = input('Введите строку: ')

    if line == '0':
        break
    else:
        lines.append(line)

print(lines)
```